# How can the default node version be set using NVM?

Tags: node.js, version, nvm

I have installed nvm (ubuntu with zsh shell) with two node version: `v6.11.5` and `v9.0.0` and the default version in nvm is the `v9.0.0`

Every time I need to change the node version

```
$ nvm list
         v6.11.5
->       v9.0.0
         system
default -> node (-> v9.0.0)
node -> stable (-> v9.0.0) (default)
stable -> 9.0 (-> v9.0.0) (default)


$ nvm v6
```

How could I change the nvm version default to define `v6.11.5`?

Answer (score 3314, accepted):

(nvm maintainer here)

`nvm alias default 6.11.5` if you want it pegged to that specific version.

You can also do `nvm alias default 16` or `nvm alias default node`.

Either way, you'll want to upgrade to the latest version of `nvm` (v0.39.2 as of this writing)

```bash
# nvm set default node.js version 16.14.2
$ nvm alias default 16.14.2
$ nvm use

$ node -v
# v16.14.2
```

Comment: Addition: alias works as long as you're not installing new versions. After installing a new node the node will be your current node to use. So if you want to prevent this behavior you have to explicitly set up nvm alias default desiredVersionOfNode after each installation or just reopen a terminal.

Comment: Use `nvm alias default node` to make the "latest" the default.

Comment: Is anyone else finding that "nvm alias default 10.17.0" isn't recognised as a command ?  nvm just gives me a list of available options... it just doesn't seem to do anything (and my "ng -v" continues to use the wrong, older, version of node.js)

Comment: @MikeGledhill are you sure you're using nvm proper? If you're using `nvm-windows`, that's an entirely different project. Actual `nvm` requires WSL to work on windows.

Comment: Doing `nvm alias default` doesn't do anything. The tag "default" changes, but a new shell is still using the not-desired-version. I found that uninstalling not needed versions works.

Comment: nvm alias default v12.13.1 not set the version as default

Comment: `nvm alias default node` to use the latest version of Node installed on your computer. Remember to use `nvm use node` (or whatever Node version you want to use) after the first command to actually change the version. 

My example (I was using version 13 as default, but having 15 on machine and wanting to set default to latest version of Node):

`nvm alias default node`
`nvm use node`


was like using (in my case):

`nvm alias default 15`
`nvm use 15`

Comment: That's right, then you can do afterwards:
nvm use default

Comment: Make sure to quit the Terminal and reopen

Comment: Might want to just use the latest long-term stable release. `nvm alias default lts/*`

Comment: I seem to need to run `nvm use default` in my `~/.bashrc` file in order to get this to work.

Comment: I'm using zsh, I also had to add `nvm use default > /dev/null` to my ~/.zprofile

Comment: For paranoid double-checking: I always open a new terminal windows/tab thereaftert, and truly verify with `nvm list` (looking at both `-->` (current version) and `default -->` (default version indeed) as well as `node -v` of course.

Comment: @LJHarb  So one question I have, when I download node by means other than nvm... They go to my `/user/local/bin/node` & `/user/local/bin/npm` (The "system copy"). Since nvm downloads them to `.nvm/versions/node`, do I need to keep the "system copy" that is in `/user/local/bin` or can I delete it?

Comment: @NateThompson that's up to you! You can certainly keep it, or delete it, as you like.

Comment: I am on version `0.39.1` of nvm, and you should run `nvm use default` **after** you have run `nvm alias default v14.7.0`, for example. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is checked as the accepted answer so please update it with the info from the comments because it is incomplete as it is and will confuse people who come here for an answer that works.

Comment: @user281681 if you mean, add "nvm use", i've just done that.

Comment: Not sure if "nvm use" will work, but I usually put the version after it, like ```nvm use 18.12.1``` or ```nvm use default```. It's clear and avoids you making an easy mistake.

Comment: `nvm use` with no arguments will use whatever's in `.nvmrc`.

Comment: If you set the PATH which includes the node path in your shell profile like `.zhrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc, you need to update it to the version you want to use. So then whenever you open a new shell session, it will points to the correct version.

Comment: `nvm use default` will do the job. Just `nvm use` is gonna find the `.nvmrc` in root and use the version set there, or will error out with `no .nvmrc found`

Comment: `nvm alias default 18.16.0` or any version results in the help info as if I ran `nvm --help`.

Comment: @JasonAyer if you're still having trouble, file an issue on the nvm repo, it's a better place to get help than SO.

Comment: But if there is no .nvmrc, `nvm use` will fail.

Comment: This will make the current LTS the default `nvm alias default stable`.

Comment: No, it won't - `stable` is an antiquated alias for `node`. If you want LTS to be the default, do `nvm alias default 'lts/*'`.

Answer (score 204):

Lets say to want to make default version as 10.19.0.

```
nvm alias default v10.19.0
```

But it will give following error

```
! WARNING: Version 'v10.19.0' does not exist.
default -> v10.19.0 (-> N/A)
```

In That case you need to run two commands in the following order

```
# Install the version that you would like 
nvm install 10.19.0

# Set 10.19.0 (or another version) as default
nvm alias default 10.19.0
```

Comment: nvm alias default 10.19.0
Without "v"

Comment: it works both with or without the v.

Comment: don't forget to `nvm use default` as @alltozall20381 mentioned below or start a new shell.

Answer (score 171):

This will set the default to be the most current version of node

```
nvm alias default node
```

and then you'll need to run

```
nvm use default
```

or exit and open a new tab

Comment: Asked for node 6, your solution will choose the last node stable version to use. So it will not use specific 6 version

Comment: Even though this is pretty useful, this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: This gave me a message "Your user’s .npmrc file (${HOME}/.npmrc)
has a `globalconfig` and/or a `prefix` setting, which are incompatible with nvm.
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v15.13.0` to unset it." I ended up running the suggested command and it worked.

Comment: Yours is the first answer that tells me to run `nvm use default` which is what I was missing.

Comment: This works for me, but only in the same shell. When I open a new one `node -v` still prints the previous version...

Comment: You can add `nvm use default` to your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` file to persist across terminal sessions.

Comment: Still working with node.js version 16 LTS and 18 LTS. Put the alias name first with the version you want to make it default, and then run nvm use "alias name (default)"

Answer (score 74):

If you want to switch only for once use this

```
nvm use 12.x
```

Else if you want to switch the default node version then use

```
nvm use default 12.x
```

or

```
nvm alias default 12.x
```

Answer (score 62):

I was trying to change the default version from a VSCode terminal on a Mac. Didnt work. I had to **run this from the default system terminal**.

`nvm alias default v16.16.0`

Comment: Just to clarify, you can also do "nvm alias default v16" and it'll stick to the v16 major version.

Comment: After running above command in macos terminal, had to restart my Vscode to see the changes applied in Vscode terminal.

Answer (score 45):

This is what works for me.

```
nvm use default v16
```

This did not do anything for me

```
nvm alias default v16
```

Comment: Notice that the `v` in `v16` matters. Without that it didn't work for me (even though it does when I use `nvm use 16`).

Comment: maybe need to restart the terminal

Answer (score 44):

If you just want a major version as default this works:

```
% nvm alias default 18
```

To check your current default:

```
% nvm alias default
default -> 18 (-> v18.12.1)
```

Restart terminal to apply.

Comment: thanks sir!
Worked for me in terminal for mac

Answer (score 38):

For those testing this in **VSCode terminal** and still seeing the old version even after killing/restarting terminal -- VS code caches the old version somehow. Close/reopen your full VSCode window and you should see the correct version with `node -v`.

Comment: I got curious about why this is case, and the best explanation I can come up with is that the vscode process must provide new shells with the $PATH variable it received when it was started. Because nvm works by updating your $PATH, new shells in vscode do not reflect those changes, and a full restart is required

Answer (score 34):

nvm alias default 16.10.0(your destination node version)

Answer (score 31):

You can also like this:

```sh
$ nvm alias default lts/fermium
```

Comment: Is there any way to target the latest version ? e.g. `nvm alias default lts/latest` ?

Comment: Try with `nvm alias default lts/*`

Comment: Note you will need to install lts/fermium first. Plus I find `nvm alias default lts/*` returns `WARNING: Version 'lts/*' does not exist.`

Answer (score 22):

***Alert:*** This answer is for MacOS only

Let suppose you have 2 versions of nodeJS inside your *nvm*, namely ***v13.10.1* & *v15.4.0***

And,
***v15.4.0*** is default

```
> nvm list
       v13.10.1
->      v15.4.0
         system
default -> 15.4.0 (-> v15.4.0)
```

**And, you want to switch the default to *v13.10.1***

Follow these steps on your Mac terminal:

1. Run the command:

   > nvm alias default 13.10.1

This will make the default point to v13.10.1 as...

```
default -> 13.10.1 (-> v13.10.1)
```

2. Open new instance of terminal. Now check the node version here as...

> node -v

**You will get...**

```
v13.10.1
```

3. nvm list will also show the new default version.

   > nvm list

**Just an info:** *The NodeJS versions taken as example above will have their different npm versions. You can cross-verify it in terminal by running* `npm -v`

Comment: Excellent step by step, thank you.  Works on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @JasonCoder, oh you're welcome sir! Thanks for pointing out for Ubuntu :)
In fact, my answer would work totally well for Linux and Windows systems too. On Windows, the user may do these steps via GitBash.

Answer (score 19):

**In Nutshell steps to use NVM**

For Mac

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
nvm install 16
nvm use 16
nvm alias default 16
npm install npm --global # Upgrade npm to the latest version
```

For Linux

```
sudo apt install curl git
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt install nodejs
```

For Windows

```
Git's installer for Windows from below link

https://git-scm.com/download/win

node-v16.XX.XX-x64.msi from below link

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/
```

Answer (score 17):

I did something like that after running a `nvm install --lts`:

```sh
nvm alias default 'lts/*'
```

Comment: Good answer! `nvm install --lts && nvm alias default lts/*`

Answer (score 14):

I tried the most-upvoted answer and didn’t work for me.
The problem was that I had another node installed by brew which NVM recognizes as system-node. **NVM prioritizes system-node over default alias.** All I had to was to uninstall the system-node (`brew uninstall node`).

Comment: Same for me on WSL. I didn't have brew so I used ´sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs´

Comment: @LDW comment did the job for me on WSL as well.

Answer (score 11):

First check available versions

```
nvm list
```

Then set default version using

```
nvm alias default lts/**
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

**nvm alias default v14.17.5**

```
   mazin ~  nvm ls
           v10.15.1
    ->     v12.19.0
           v14.17.5
           v16.14.0
    default -> 12 (-> v12.19.0)
    node -> stable (-> v16.14.0) (default)
    stable -> 16.14 (-> v16.14.0) (default)
    iojs -> N/A (default)
    unstable -> N/A (default)
    lts/* -> lts/gallium (-> v16.14.0)
    lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
    lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
    lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
    lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
    lts/erbium -> v12.22.10 (-> N/A)
    lts/fermium -> v14.19.0 (-> N/A)
    lts/gallium -> v16.14.0

     mazin ~  nvm use 14
    Now using node v14.17.5 (npm v8.7.0)

     mazin@zhihongtongxue  ~  nvm ls
           v10.15.1
           v12.19.0
    ->     v14.17.5
           v16.14.0
    default -> 12 (-> v12.19.0)
    node -> stable (-> v16.14.0) (default)
    stable -> 16.14 (-> v16.14.0) (default)
    iojs -> N/A (default)
    unstable -> N/A (default)
    lts/* -> lts/gallium (-> v16.14.0)
    lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
    lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
    lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
    lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
    lts/erbium -> v12.22.10 (-> N/A)
    lts/fermium -> v14.19.0 (-> N/A)
    lts/gallium -> v16.14.0

     mazin ~  nvm alias default 14
    default -> 14 (-> v14.17.5)

     mazin ~  nvm ls
           v10.15.1
           v12.19.0
    ->     v14.17.5
           v16.14.0
    default -> 14 (-> v14.17.5)
    node -> stable (-> v16.14.0) (default)
    stable -> 16.14 (-> v16.14.0) (default)
    iojs -> N/A (default)
    unstable -> N/A (default)
    lts/* -> lts/gallium (-> v16.14.0)
    lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
    lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
    lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
    lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
    lts/erbium -> v12.22.10 (-> N/A)
    lts/fermium -> v14.19.0 (-> N/A)
    lts/gallium -> v16.14.0
```

Answer (score 8):

Since there are a lot of answers above that talk about the default alias, and someone still can't get the right version in new terminal, my answer is here.

while you add `source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh` in your shell rc file(like ~/.bashrc), it will first check whether there is a nvm-version node path in the $PATH environment variable, like `/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v14.1.0/bin`. If there is one, nvm will not use default alias.

So firstly you should check why there is node path in $PATH. If you could get the reason(like run `nvm use 16` explicitly in another rc file or script file), just remove it.

If you can't get reason or just wanna keep it, then another solution is:

```bash
# that's your previous usage, keep it
source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh

# FORCE to use default alias
nvm use default

# or if you prefer to forcedly use .nvmrc prior to default, then
test -f .nvmrc && nvm use || nvm use default
```

Answer (score 7):

`nvm alias default 16` (where "16" is the version you want to use) but if you're install node from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ before I would suggest you remove it first. For m1 or m1 pro chips, I suggest you follow this solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fULL8QiPEU4

Answer (score 5):

The current answers did not solve the problem for me, because I had node installed in /usr/bin/node and /usr/local/bin/node - so the system always resolved these first, and ignored the nvm version.

I solved the issue by moving the existing versions to /usr/bin/node-system and /usr/local/bin/node-system

Then I had no node command anymore, until I used nvm use :(

I solved this issue by creating a symlink to the version that would be installed by nvm.

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node-system    
sudo mv /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/node-system 
nvm use node
  Now using node v12.20.1 (npm v6.14.10)
which node
  /home/paul/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node
sudo ln -s /home/paul/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

Then open a new shell

```
node -v
  v12.20.1
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the default version to use the latest LTS version
`nvm alias default lts/*`

You manually upgrade the global version by doing `nvm install lts/* --reinstall-packages-from=lts/*` or a weekly cron job if you want to keep your version up to date

The `--reinstall-packages-from=lts/*` is there to reinstall the global packages you had everytime you change versions

Answer (score 5):

I used the accepted answer like so:

```
$ nvm alias default 12.22.12
```

However when I closed and opened the terminal it was always defaulting to the previous verion.

One very important thing for Linux systems at least (I use Fedora), is that ***you have to restart the machine to take effect***. After that, nvm default was working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

If your node version (`node -v`) is => 16.17.0, then run `nvm alias default 20.9.0` to have `node -v => 20.9.0`

Comment: I find your post so hard to read that I am not even sure whether you actually meant to answer (according to [answer]). If so, please [edit] to make it more obvious. Otherwise please delete this.

Answer (score 2):

change the default node version with `nvm alias default 10.15.3` *

*(replace mine version with your default version number)*

you can check your default lists with `nvm list`

Answer (score 2):

#Worked for me 100%
Follow this for default node version:

> nvm install 12.13.1
> then,
> nvm alias default 12.13.1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have the correct version of node installed globally. Your company might be using a different version.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation of `Windows 11`, `nvm 1.1.9` and using `gitbash`

These work for me (have to **run as administrator**)

[lastest version]

`nvm use latest`

[specific version]

`nvm use 18.10.0`

These didn't work for me

`nvm use 18` -> return `node vv18.10.0 (64-bit) is not installed or cannot be found.`

`nvm use default 18` -> return `Unrecognized version: "default"`

`nvm alias ...` -> seems `alias` command is not supported in this nvm version

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 1):

FYI looks like tmux caches the old version also (like mentioned with VSCode above). restarting tmux then uses the new version for each window.

Comment: That was it! I had new version of node only in first pane, when I opened new one I got the old version. `tmux kill-server` helped.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was, my nvm was not set every time I open a new terminal. Once I got rid of this issue, default node version was also being set fine.

After the nvm was intializing on startup of new terminal, the node version was being initialized to the default set via nvm.[Here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2311#issuecomment-898877308)

Answer (score -4):

`nvm alias default <node version>`

this will make the `<node version>` default.

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what half of the other answers are already saying, including the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47787025/14267427).

Answer (score -5):

While NVM has its uses, I encourage you to consider an alternate option.

You can pin you project to a particular version of Node.js using [the `node` package on Npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node)!

```bash
cd oldProject

npm i node@6.11.5

cd ../newProject

npm i node@9.0.0
```

Next time Npm runs `node`, it will use that version!

The [`node` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node) accomplishes this by downloading the specified version of Node.js to `node_modules/.bin/node`. You you can run it directly, but it is easier to let Npm run it.

Any `package.json#scripts` will automatically use the specified version of `node` since `node_modules/.bin` is added to the path by Npm.

No more remembering which version of Node this package uses.
No need to run anything new - just make sure `npm i` has been run.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "node-version": "node --version"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node": "9.0.0"
  }
}
```

Note, you will need to `npm install` once before the correct `node` is used:

```bash
node --version
# v18.12.0
npm run node-version
# v18.12.0
npm install
npm run node-version
# v9.0.0
node --version
# v18.12.0
node_modules/.bin/node --version
# v9.0.0
```

Answer (score -11):

nvm list <---- to get all available node vesions

nvm use v16 <----------- to switch your desired version

node -v <------------- to check the node version

Comment: use vxxx does not change the default.

Comment: question is how we can set default node version using nvm. your answer is not solution for question