# how to set the default node version?? After restarting server

Tags: node.js, nvm

```
$ nvm ls:

     .nvm
 v0.11.12
 v0.11.13
```

I have to keep hitting nvm use v.0.11.13 in every session:

```
     .nvm
 v0.11.12
```

->   v0.11.13
I've tried both the brew install, as well as the official installation script.

Comment: after restarting the server it's again set to old verision

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set NVM node version default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190861/set-nvm-node-version-default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a `.nvmrc` file at the root of your project. It shall contain:

```
v0.11.13
```

Then, you could add this little snippet at the end of your `~/.bashrc` (or whatever bash you're using):

```
# Use node version (nvm use)
autoload -U add-zsh-hook
load-nvmrc() {
  if [[ -f .nvmrc && -r .nvmrc ]]; then
    nvm use
  elif [[ $(nvm version) != $(nvm version default)  ]]; then
    echo "Reverting to nvm default version"
    nvm use default
  fi
}
add-zsh-hook chpwd load-nvmrc
load-nvmrc
```

This should properly set the `node` version as soon as you enter a directory containing a proper `.nvmrc` file.

Answer (score 5):

use this in the terminal.

```
$ nvm alias default v0.11.13
```

for more help go to https://github.com/creationix/nvm or write `nvm help` in terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but we already tried this but after restarted  the server it's again going to old version

Comment: Run it again and then write this `nvm ls` check which version default is on