# Changing node version with "nvm use <version>" not changed after I re open terminal window

Tags: macos, terminal, nvm, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

In oh-my-zsh file I added nvm by changing the line in the .zshrc file.

> plugins=(git nvm) // added nvm

so now I see nvm and use it from the terminal

but when I change the version seen below.

[image]

Then I close the terminal and open a new one and check the version and it still shows using the previous version! It hasn't kept the change.

New window

[image]

Comment: See an answer to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24587177/1102322

Comment: You need to make it to be default version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190861/how-can-the-default-node-version-be-set-using-nvm

Comment: Can you share your `cat  ~/.zshrc` ( the content of .zshrc). Often doing nvm alias default {version to choose} then nvm use default {version} helps. Please check that if it works for you.  Often adding `export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh` at the end of `.zshrc` helps. or could be an issue with the `PATH` variable. Not sure which one is triggering the issue. But let's inspect all these things. If nothing works please share the contents of `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to run this command

```
nvm i v12.18.1
```

then

```
nvm alias default v12.18.1
```