# npm install vercel fails for wrong node version though it is correct

Tags: npm, next.js, vercel

I am trying to install the Vercel package:

```
$ sudo npm i -g vercel

> vercel@19.2.0 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vercel
> node ./scripts/preinstall.js

> Error! Detected unsupported Node.js version.
Expected ">= 10" but found "8.10.0".
Please update to the latest Node.js LTS version to install Vercel CLI.
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for vercel@19.2.0: wanted: {"node":">= 10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"6.14.6"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: vercel@19.2.0

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vercel@19.2.0 preinstall: `node ./scripts/preinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the vercel@19.2.0 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

It claims my node version is not above v10 but when I do the following it shows:

```
 $ node -v
v12.18.2
```

And npm:

```
 $ npm -v
6.14.6
```

So who is lying? ;) Whats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check if that version is the default with `nvm list`.

For more info on setting the default version, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190861/how-can-the-default-node-version-be-set-using-nvm).