# How can I call "nvm use" in a bash script, and have the selected node version retained after the script executes?

Tags: node.js, bash, nvm

For a build process that requires updating from Node.js 12 to 14, I'd like a bash script to detect whether `nvm` is installed, and, if so, do `nvm use v14` (or `nvm install v14` if necessary), and then I want the nvm-selected node version to stick at 14 *after the bash script terminates*, not just for the duration of the script.

I can switch to v14 with this script, but after the script has terminated, the shell environment remains at v12:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
source ~/.bashrc

nvm --version
echo $NVM_BIN
node --version
nvm use v14
echo $NVM_BIN
node --version
```

Just executing the `nvm` command in a bash script is a pain because `nvm` isn't a true command, but a shell function, and the script has to use the first three lines to set up `nvm` for the script.

The output is:

```text
0.33.11
/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin
v12.21.0
Now using node v14.16.0 (npm v6.14.11)
/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin
v14.16.0
```

When the script is finished, however:

[image]

I think the trick might be making sure the environment variable `NVM_BIN` persists at the v14 path when the script exits, but I don't know how to do that. In fact, I think it's generally not allowed for the shell in which a script executes to change environment variables in the parent shell.

The `nvm` commmand, however, is itself a shell script, and whatever it does is persistent after it's done executing. There should be some way for me to make this happen too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you set an alias with nvm for default,

```sh
nvm alias default 14.0.0
```

the node version will persist across any new terminal instances.

Comment: Looked good for a moment there... but sadly, it didn't work.

Comment: Well... maybe. If I close the terminal I was in, and open the terminal again, then the new default kicks in. That _might_ be good enough, as long as another process started up from the main script inherits this change too, without exiting the original terminal. You at least deserve an up-vote for at least getting me part way. :)

Comment: You can probably try the options mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190861/how-can-the-default-node-version-be-set-using-nvm

Comment: Not sure, why this was marked as a solution, but it's definitely not addressing the core of the problem. I'm also wondering how to call the `nvm` instance of the terminal which invoked the script, and persist the changed node version *particularly* in that instance. Updating the system-wide value for every new instance - not an option

Answer (score 0):

To have the selected node version after the script executes you can run it like this:

```bash
. change-node-version.sh
```

**script**

```bash
node --version
nvm use 14.18.0
node --version
```

[image: output]

then:

```bash
node --version
➜  v14.18.0
```