# Node Version Manager issues

Tags: node.js, nvm

I installed Node Version Manager on my device and ran `nvm install 8.8.1`, but now when I try to update to 18 it doesn't work. Every time I start up my machine I have to run `nvm use 18`.

I need to make sure it is always on 18. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can the default node version be set using NVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190861/how-can-the-default-node-version-be-set-using-nvm)

Comment: @Konrad I saw it, and It got me excited. I ran the command `nvm alias default 18`, created new folder, and ran `node -v1', sure enough, output was 8.8.1

Comment: did you also try the other answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72532347/5272567

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```bash
nvm alias default 18

nvm use 18
```