# nvm setup wrong version when attempting to use playwright

Tags: node.js, playwright, nvm, playwright-test

I've been trying to get playwright to work, attempting to run a basic test but when I do it pops up a message telling me

`The node version in "/usr/local/bin/node" is outdated (version 4.4.3)`

but if I run nvm ls I get this

```
        v19.0.0
->       system
default -> 8.1.0 (-> N/A)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v19.0.0) (default)
stable -> 19.0 (-> v19.0.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/hydrogen (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.20.1 (-> N/A)
lts/hydrogen -> v18.16.1 (-> N/A)
```

And if I run `nvm -v` I get

`0.39.1`

Can anyone help suggest what Im missing here? I've run nvm use 19.0.0 tried removing version 0.39.1 and tried restarting multiple times but it doesn't seem to update the version :/

Answer (score 0):

Playwright currently supports `node` version `16` or newer. You have version `4.4.3` on your system path which is ancient. Playwright doesn't know about `nvm` and what it does, it just wants `node` on the path. You need to find out where `nvm` puts its node versions and add that location to the `PATH` environment variable, see here: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/18397

I don't know `nvm` well as I use `nvs` but I am guessing you will need to create a `default`: [How can the default node version be set using NVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190861/how-can-the-default-node-version-be-set-using-nvm)