# How to make a version of NODE default?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

When I restart the terminal in NODE it goes back to version 16, but I want to make version 18 the default, without having to run the command "nvm use 18.17.1" every time.
I thank.

With NODE 18 installed, I uninstalled the NODE 16 version, and when executing the "node -v" command it gave an error stating that NODE was not installed. So I needed to run the "nvm use 18.17.1" command once again.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a default version by running: "nvm alias default vX.Y.Z".

Reference:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/

Comment: Better to link to the official documentation ~ https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#set-default-node-version

Comment: One line answer from the nvm maintainer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/47787025/9098718