# Set default node version

Tags: node.js, nvm, nvm-windows

I am attempting to set the default version of node to 14 using the following commands

`nvm install 14`

`nvm alias default 14`

But I only get a list of available commands instead...
[image]

running `node --version` returns v20.10.0, which is the version I installed, but I thought the install 14 command above should install 14, the setting alias default 14 would set the default to 14.

I tried following instructions above from here...

[How can the default node version be set using NVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190861/how-can-the-default-node-version-be-set-using-nvm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are on Windows OS, in which case you probably use [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows), and *not* the original [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) tool, which works only on POSIX type OS (i.e. Linux, macOS).

`nvm alias` command only exists for the latter, there is no equivalent for nvm-windows.

The SO post you refer to is about nvm for Linux.

---

IIRC, `nvm install` with nvm-windows does *not* switch the current Node version; you have to explicitly call `nvm use` after installation.

Furthermore, nvm-windows switches the Node version globally (using Windows PATH), so there is no point in having a default version.